# How to show user location on custom map?

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, geocode

I want to show user location and other object location on custom map as follows :

For that I have Googled the things that says "we need to convert the lat long data in to X Y Coordinates in the image and then we need to show it on image"

Other option I found is geocode the image to show the location data.

I didn't find anything else other than this.  Can anyone please guide me to show user current location on the custom map as follows?

Comment: its not indoor navigation..its just example of map actaull thing is i have custom map for outdoor region and there i have to show current location

Answer (score 1):

For translating your lattitude and longitute you should know the projection of your custom map. Then you can use [PROJ.4](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) open source library to convert them. Or you can hardcode translation function to you app. For example, [here at GitHub](https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/871897) you may found code to translate from lat&lon to EPSG:900913 (google mercator projection)

Comment: its not indoor navigation

Comment: @BhavikKama my answer is still valid. Added one example link

Comment: can you please explain bit more...?

Comment: @BhavikKama I have a demo project at [GitHub](https://github.com/Azat92/CustomMap) which is doing exactly what you want. I hope it will help you to understand how to solve your issue - simple run and turn on location simulation somewhere. I created that project a time ago, so right now I updated it to iOS 8 Location Manager requirements, but PROJ.4 library doesn't have x64 slice, so please run it for example on iPad 2 simulator (or any non 64 bit device)

Comment: i have some questions.. can we please have some chat at your availbale time?

Comment: nope we can even chat on fb as i have my fb account added in stackoverflow